# Python Spyder stops responding

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have **Spyder 2.3.8** that I installed with Anaconda.

**Python version is 2.7.11, conda version is 4.0.5.**

I have found that some types of code make the Spyder editor stop responding. One example is the line:

```
x = b'\x89\x50\x4E\x47\x0D\x0A\x1A\x0A'
```

I assume this is a valid python code. I am relatively new to Python, so please correct me if I am wrong here. I tried in on a terminal on the Python shell and it works.

Another very strange example is

```
png = 'oxy.png'

f = open(png, 'rb') 
f.read(10) # That executes without any problems
f.close()

f = open(png, 'rb') 
x = f.read(10) # this line makes Spyder freeze!
f.close()
```

The only difference here is that I assign `f.read()` to a variable, and that makes Spyder stop responding!

I just updated Spyder and all other anaconda packages. The error was happening before and it still happens. Any idea of what I could be doing wrong, or what could I try?

EDIT: There was this other part of the question which has been explained already (thanks!)

I also tried to run the following example I found on the internet:

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
print("Nice to meet you " + name + "!")
```

This example gives me an exception. Here is the full output:

```
name = input("What's your name? ")
print("Nice to meet you " + name + "!")

What is your name? sininho
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-e82cc0e3f7a3>", line 1, in <module>
    name = input("What's your name? ")

  File "/scr/elbe9/pauline/physio/program/python_libraries/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 165, in <lambda>
    builtin_mod.input = lambda prompt='': eval(self.raw_input(prompt))

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

NameError: name 'sininho' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, the `input()` function executes the *code* you type in. To get q string, use `raw_input()` function which works the same way.